# Parsing of YAML file with Jackson fails if value starts with special character

Tags: kotlin, jackson, yaml, jackson-databind

I am trying to parse the following YAML-content:

```yaml
template:
    amplitude: 5
    noise: +-0.01
```

This fails with this exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: empty String (through reference chain: ... ->my.package.Template["noise"])
```

The class `Template` contains a property `noise` of type `FlexValue`. I made a custom `JsonDeserializer` that is responsible to parse the values for properties of this type. The notation allows somewhat fancy expressions, hence the name `FlexValue` for the type. The value in this example, "+-0.01", is a valid input for the deserializer. However, it seems like the deserializer isn't even called. **The exception seems to be thrown before that.**

Here is the relevant class definition of my custom deserializer:

```kotlin
class FlexValueParser : JsonDeserializer<FlexValue>() {

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): FlexValue {
        //...
    }

}
```

The custom deserializer is registered as follows:

```kotlin
@JsonDeserialize(using = FlexValueParser::class)
class FlexValue {
    // ...
}
```

This setup seems to work fine. It does on other types as well, which are parsed differently.

If I prepend a "0" before "+-", which is also a valid input, it works:

```yaml
template:
    amplitude: 5
    noise: 0+-0.01
```

Is "+-" a special cahracter in YAML that causes Jackson to fail parsing it, because it tries to do something else than I expect? I expect it to treat the input "+-0.01" as a `String` because it doesn't represent a valid number input.

The same problem occurs, when I use `noise: ~0.01`, which is also a valid input for my deserializer. The same exception is thrown on this and can be avoided by prepending a "0" before the curly "~".

Can someone give me a hint on this?

Comment: `+-` carries no special meaning in YAML and the exception you get implies it is parsed properly and data binding fails. I do not know why this is happening and it seems like being a bug in the data mapper, since there shouldn't be anything happening there that could cause this error when you provide a custom deserializer.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So you mean it would be good to file a bug for this problem in the Jackson repo?

Comment: Certainly. At the very least, the error message *empty string* is wrong and should be fixed.

Comment: Ok. Since you've answered my question I'd like to mark your answer as accepted. So if you like, repost your previous comment as an answer.

Comment: Filed a bug report here: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/issues/281

Comment: I'd rather wait for someone to respond to the issue and have whatever they say about it as answer since the problem is unresolved. I don't really crave for those internet points ;)

Comment: Recreated a minimal example and that runs fine: https://gist.github.com/mpdgraev/c973db00f7e7c4dee6c1613b540fc0ec , maybe check if you have the latest dataformat-yaml version (I used 2.12.4)

Comment: While trying to make a failing example for the Jackson folks on Github I found the source of the problem, which had nothing to do with Jackson or YAML at all, but rather with a failing Regex expression in Kotlin in my custom deserializer. Parsing the YAML content actually did reach my custom deserializer. I must have set the wrong breakpoint to get this wrong. Sorry for the noise and thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the source of the problem, which had nothing to do with Jackson or YAML. Closing this question therefore.